# Can't insert type text in Mysql using python 2.7

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 and MySQl. I have a column of type text(65535)

My connection is correct and the insert statement work until I add the field `mod`, it gives error that says:

> ERROR 1406 IN CONNECTION: Data too long for column 'col6' at row 1

Knowing that I am inserting variables which already calculated in the program earlier. The value6 is type string. I made sure by using `type()` function. The col6 is of type tinytext. I made sure using:

```
show columns in mydb.mytable
```

Here is the SQL statement in my python code.

```
sql = """INSERT INTO mytable(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""

try:
   # Execute the SQL command
   cursor.execute(sql,(value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6))
   # Commit your changes in the database
   db.commit()
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   db.rollback()
   print "ERROR %d IN CONNECTION: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
```

Could you please point the problem?

**EDIT:**
col6 contains a string of 512 hex. character. It contains a public key that I obtained it using:

```
pk=x509.get_pubkey()
mod=pk.get_modulus()
```

I checked the return type:

```
print type(mod)
```

I am sorry that I can not post the whole code. But the problem arise only when I insert this column. Before that, it is all right.

and I get `str`

Comment: Can you also make sure by showing us the schema and what data you are cramming into it. Because basically you are showing us no tables or the data attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tinytext only holds 255 chars:

"TINYTEXT [CHARACTER SET charset_name] [COLLATE collation_name]

A TEXT column with a maximum length of 255 (28 − 1) characters. The effective maximum length is less if the value contains multibyte characters. Each TINYTEXT value is stored using a 1-byte length prefix that indicates the number of bytes in the value."
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html